# Cronjob to run every n years and n weeks for django-celery-beat

Tags: python-3.x, django, cron, django-celery-beat, django-crontab

I want to create a reminder very similar to google calendar custom reminder feature.
Where user can select number of days/weeks/months/years using djano-celery periodic task and crontab.
For eg I want a task to run on every 26th May in every 2 years what can be the expression.
After research I found the below expression but it is not working.

`58 10 26 5/24 *`
For this i am getting the below result in crontab generator
[image]

Similarly I want a task to run on every Thursday and Friday which repeats in every 2 weeks.
As per my research it should be like
`30 10 */14 * 4,5` 
[image]

But this as well is not working.
I want django-celery-crontab expression.